# Ubuntu Calendar does not give me notifications

Tags: 18.04, calendar

Ubuntu calendar is not giving me reminders despite having notifications on and reminders set. Does anyone have a solution for this? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the actual part that shows the calendar notifications belongs to the evolution package, which is not installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04. If you install it, and then set up the calendar from there, it will show notifications for the events.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with no results. I suspect that configuration is the problem. What exactly is needed?

Comment: If you install Evolution mail, with sudo apt-get install evolution, it should work. Set up the calendar from within Evolution, and then when you set up an event, don't forget to set the reminder. 
Alternatively, you could use Thunderbird's Lightning extension. Install it from the extensions menu in Thunderbird, together with the EDS integration extension and the evolution package. That way, events you created on lightning will show the reminders.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately, it does not work. If I use desktop notifications in Google, notifications from events are received but notifications reminders are not. There are many posts on the Internet and on Google community sites complaining about this. My workaround is to simply use zero-length events in place of reminders.

Comment: It used to work, but for some reason, it stopped working :/ I'm not sure how to set it up. Maybe the next Ubuntu versions can ship with a working notification system.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Calendar app notifications is enabled.

Go to **Settings > Notifications** find the Calendar app, and make sure notifications are turned **on**.